# is it possible to fetch the object value without calling a new activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I know that stuff of calling the new activity and pass the object value from one activity to another by using putExtra and getExtra function. but i want to pass the value without calling and start the new activity. Is it possible ?
If yes then let me know how i can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the Application class for declaring global variables

```
class Globalclass extends Application {

  private String myState;

  public String getState(){
    return myState;
  }
  public void setState(String s){
    myState = s;
  }
}

class TempActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ...
    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    String state = appState.getState();
    ...
  }
}
```

**UPDATED :**

Checkout this nice Tutorial about how to do that.

[Application Class Using as Global](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state)

Comment: Thanks Suri from India. But what about storing the data ? Will you please update the code with the methods to store the data from other activity  ?

Comment: Well, you can store the data in the same manner using setState("state set").

Comment: That's not a good way of storing data. I used to use this method but it appeared to be error-prone. For example, if you save some data in this manner and then run another application that requires a lot of memory your application will be terminated and this global state will be lost.

Comment: Suppose i have number of data. in your case there are number of myState. Now is it possible to fetch all the state from another activity ? and in case if i m not using the getter setter method for same time then ??

Comment: Checkout my updated answer, in which I had given a link of example how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

for this you can use `static variable` or `SharedPreferences` or if you heavy data then you can use `SQlite`.

Comment: I dont want to use SQLite because i already have it. So is there any other alternate ?

Comment: if you don't need that value when app starts again then try to use static variables..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use handler's handleMessage() and pass the object in a message .

```
            Handler handler =  new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            }
            };
```

You can then call handler.handleMessage(msg), you can assign any object to msg.onj

Answer (score 1):

You can take the help of database like SQLite or you may go for Constant class concept where you can make a public static variable and store your data in one activity and access in other activity.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There're a lot of ways to pass a value to an activity:

- You can use an `Intent` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. In this case `onNewIntent()` method will be called for already started activity.
- You can use static fields or static methods to pass new data to your activity. But it's not a good method really because sometimes application is terminated even if it's foreground and all static data is lost.
- You can send new data to an activity using broadcast messages. In this case the activity must register a `BroadcastReceiver`.

I think it's not very difficult to make up a few more ways to pass arguments.